# File is taking input infinitely

Tags: c, file-io

I have following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f1, *f2, *f3;
    int number, i;

    printf("Contents of data file\n\n");

    f1=fopen("DATA", "w");

    for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if(number==-1)
        {
            break;
        }

        putw(number,f1);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    f1=fopen("DATA","r");
    f2=fopen("ODD","w");
    f3=fopen("EVEN","w");

    while((number=getw(f1)) != EOF)
    {
        if(number%2==0)
        {
            putw(number,f3);
        }

        else
        {
            putw(number,f2);
        }
    }

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);

    f2=fopen("ODD","r");
    f2=fopen("EVEN","r");

    printf("Contents on ODD file:");
    while((number=getw(f2)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%4d", number);
    } 

    printf("Contents on EVEN file:");
    while((number=getw(f3)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%4d", number);
    }

    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);

    return 0;

}
```

This program is taking input infinitely for **FILE f1**. After pressing **-1** it should be terminated. But its not! I have pressed `CTRL+D`. But nothing happened.  I am not understanding where is the problem.

Comment: i have checked it at my side it is coming out of loop when -1 is pressed. Do you press enter after every input? you should go step by step where is the going in infinite loop.

Comment: yes, I press enter after every input.

Comment: does it not coming out from loop even after inputting 11 number?

Comment: yes. it is not exiting loop for more than 10 inputs!

Comment: then check your f1 handle is valid or not i.e. it is Putw is working properly? in which compiler you are trying?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50087/discussion-between-heena-goyal-and-scotia)

Comment: Really want `==` in `while((number==getw(f1)) != EOF)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written

```
f2=fopen("ODD","r");
f2=fopen("EVEN","r");
```

but it should be written

```
f2=fopen("ODD","r");
f3=fopen("EVEN","r");
```

any way, heena has corrected this... the EVEN stream should be pointed by f3

Answer (score 4):

i guess you mean

`(number=getw(f1))`

instead of

`(number==getw(f1))`

Your program is going to loop forever on your first `while` clause in this way.

And you should be opening your files with `"wb"` and `"rb"` instead of `"w"` and `"r"`, because `putw()` and `getw()` both expect files opened in binary mode.

Comment: No. It should be `(number=getw(f1))`. Cause I am reading input from the file and assigning them in number.

Comment: @Scotia that's exactly what i'm saying. Your code shows `(number==getw(f1))`

Comment: I have edited my code. Now my code is taking 10 inputs. But the problem is here is showing a lot of unknown character in my compiler.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the same code with some small corrections and it is working fine try this if helpful:

```
int main()
{
 FILE *f1, *f2, *f3;
int number, i;

printf("Contents of data file\n\n");

f1=fopen("DATA", "w");

for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if(number==-1)
    {
        break;
    }

    putw(number,f1);
}
fclose(f1);
f1=fopen("DATA","r");
f2=fopen("ODD","w");
f3=fopen("EVEN","w");

while((number=getw(f1)) != EOF)
{
    if(number%2==0)
    {
        putw(number,f3);
    }

    else
    {
        putw(number,f2);
    }
}

fclose(f1);
fclose(f2);
fclose(f3);

f2=fopen("ODD","r");
f3=fopen("EVEN","r");

printf("Contents on ODD file:");
while((number=getw(f2)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%4d", number);
} 

printf("Contents on EVEN file:");
while((number=getw(f3)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%4d", number);
}

fclose(f2);
fclose(f3);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: This code is not working. Showing error on `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`. And also I'm not understanding what does it mean.